# Android Emulator's Overlay Occupies Area on Desktop in Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've been doing development with Flutter. I was using a real hardware but wanted to use an emulator. I set it up but there's this issue.

I usually put my apps in virtual desktops and I switch between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+[arrow keys]. Each of them have a special purpose, usually desktop 1 is for browsing, desktop 2 is for development and desktop 4 is extra (for testing UI apps and emulator in this case).

However, after I launch Android emulator and switch to a different desktop, it results in the issue seen below:

[image]

The red area you see stays unresponsive for other apps such as browser, VSCode etc. (i.e. does not respond to clicks). That area is where the emulator is on Desktop 4. And it also keeps showing multitouch tool.

It's a bit annoying so I wanted to ask if anyone got this issue and if they have any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Kubuntu 20.04
- AMD Radeon R7 240/340

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

I have, somehow in a weird way, found a workaround for this issue.

After having this issue, go to the emulator window and press the magnifying glass with a plus button icon twice.

[image: the location of that button]

After that, it will drop that weird multitouch state and it won't bother you even as you switch desktop.

Rebooting computer will result in the same bug, however, you have to do it again.

## Solution 2

Another method that works is to simply resize the window. If you have a device frame on your emulator, you can simply hold down the Meta key and hold right click and resize your window.

## Solution 3

You can also maximize the window. If you have device frame around emulator window, you can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, which opens up window options menu, then click "Maximize". This will get rid of it.